# Unable to build TypeScript application in Docker due to bcrypt / Make issue

Tags: docker, bcrypt

I have a GraphqQL backend application which I've forked from https://github.com/w3tecch/express-typescript-boilerplate

I've been building my fork of the app in Docker successfully for a long time, however it suddenly started failing out of the blue not long ago. I suspect it's due to one of the dependencies changing in one of the Dockerfiles.

This is what I now see when building the app in Docker:

```
=> ERROR [stage-build 3/5] RUN yarn install   
...
#12 29.39 error /project/node_modules/bcrypt: Command failed.
#12 29.39 Exit code: 1
...
#12 29.39 gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
#12 29.39 make: Entering directory '/project/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
#12 29.39 make: printf: Operation not permitted
#12 29.39 make: *** [bcrypt_lib.target.mk:103: Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127
#12 29.39 make: Leaving directory '/project/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! build error 
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/project/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/project/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v57"
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! cwd /project/node_modules/bcrypt
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
#12 29.39 gyp ERR! not ok 
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/project/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/project/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v57' (1)
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/project/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /project/node_modules/bcrypt
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
#12 29.39 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
#12 29.39 Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/project/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/project/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v57' (1) executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install]: exit code: 1
------
```

The Dockerfile structure is as follows:

1. olliecaine/base (an Alpine container containing Node)
2. olliecaine/dev (extends from olliecaine/base to add additional dev dependencies such as Chromium)
3. The application's Dockerfile which has 3 stages:

   1. Develop - installs application dependencies and runs `npm run dev`
   2. Build - lints, tests and builds the app
   3. Host - uses olliecaine/base to host the app

These Dockerfiles can be found in my devops repo at https://github.com/olivercaine/devops

Everything relating to the issue can be found in https://github.com/olivercaine/express-typescript-boilerplate/blob/bugfix/docker-build-error/README%20-%20BUILD%20ISSUE.md

If anyone has any recommendation of how I can debug/fix the issue it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The failure is in `make` which is trying to compile the binary dependancies for the package. `make` is throwing the following error `*** [bcrypt_lib.target.mk:103: Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127` before it returns to `npm` with exit code `2`.

Such problems are usually associated with missing dependancies (compiler tools, libraries, etc.). There is already similar issue opened with `bycrypt` on [GitHub](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/650).

As per the GitHub thread, the library requires C/C++ compiler, make and Python as a build-set dependancies. For `alpine` this would be

```
RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk && \
    apk add libffi-dev openssl-dev && \
    apk add python-dev python3-dev
```